# AS3 - getting variable named in order within a function

Tags: actionscript-3

I am sorry if this is a beginner's question.

I made some Arrays named like `map01, map02` and so on... As you can see, I'm making a tile-based flash here. And I need to make a function that when you input a number like: `createmap(1);` it will get the variable `map01` and use the information.

Can I do anything like: `var temp:Array = Array(["map" + valueInput]);`??

Please tell me if you need anything more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of having variables with indices in their names, you should create an array of them. Here, an array of arrays.

So you just have to call `var temp:Array = maps[valueInput] as Array;`.

If you really don't want to do that and stick with your n variables, you can write

```
var index:String = valueInput.toString();
if (index.length == 1) 
   index = "0" + index; //have the index on two digits "01", "02"
var temp:Array = this["map" + index];
```

Note that it will only work for your 99 first variables (oh God...)

Comment: Sorry, I am really a beginner, but I have one more question.

Comment: `var curscore:Array = score[levelint] as Array;`
`passscore.text = "Pass: " + String(curscore[1]);`
`perfectscore.text = "Perfect: " + String(curscore[2]);`

Comment: it said Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type Number. What can I do?

Comment: You should open a new question for a new problem. But here, as it says, either passscore or perfectscore is a `Number` and your treat it as a `TexField`. Be careful not to call a variable with the same name as a clip on your stage.